# Submit a form posting some data to a ActionResult method in MVC ASP.NET and be Redirected to the respective View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I'm studying about `AngularJS` and I have a doubt about how we can submit a form and what we expect.

What I want is that when I submit a Form, I'll be redirected to another View.

So, with `$http` in Angular, I Post some data to my method `Bills_Angular` that exist in my  MVC Controller, so, if this method return a View, I expect that I'll be redirected to respective View, and in Firebug this request exists and returns the page, but not appears the page for me.

**Angular Controller**

```
var myModule= angular.module('myModule', ['ngRoute']);

myModule.controller("newBillsToPayController", function ($scope, $http, $location) {

    // Handle Button 'Finish' click
    $scope.btnFinish = function () {
        $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "Bills_Angular",
            data: {
                Fornecedor: $scope.fornecedor
            },
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } 
        }).success(function (data) {  
              $location.path("/Bills_Angular");
        }).error(function () {
            alert("Error");
        });
    };
});
```

**Form**

```
<form method="post" name="formulary">
    <div class="panel-body ng-scope" ng-controller="newBillsToPayController">
        <newbillstopay></newbillstopay>
        <div class="col-md-11" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
            <button ng-click="btnFinish()" class="btn btn-success" id="btnFinish" style="box-shadow: none; float: right;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Finish</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**ASP.NET MVC Controller**

```
   public ActionResult Bills_Angular(Models.NewBills model)
   {            
      return View(model);
   }
```

Here's what I saw in Firebug (The name is different because I translated my question to make easier to understand)

[image]

**UPDATE**

- Addedd the `'ngRoute'` to my module and associated the `angular-route.js` script to my View.
- In the controller, in `success` I put the $location and call my View.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I've spent hours on this problem can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you making ajax call to server you can't redirect on server side that has to be done on client side

Use $location.path("/route");

```
var   myModule = angular.module('myModule', [ngRoute]);

     myModule.controller("newBillsToPayController", function ($scope, $http, $location) {

            // Handle Button 'Finish' click
            $scope.btnFinish = function () {
                $http({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "Bills_Angular",
                    data: {
                        Fornecedor: $scope.fornecedor
                    },
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } 
                }).success(function (data) {  
               //to change the angular view use $location t0 redirect
                  $location.path("/route-where-you-want-to-go");
               //to redirect to page outside current angular app use 'window.location':
               //window.location = "/path-where-you-want-to-go

                }).error(function () {
                    alert("Error");
                });
            };
        });
```

Comment: I'm creating a simple application just for study, but with your sample I'll need config a route ? I try your code with `$location` but it added in URL the path that I put in this method.

Comment: Hi just don't forget to add  angular-route.js script and inject ngRoute to your app like var app = angular.module('app', [ngRoute]);

Comment: Doing this, I put the js in my View and in my module I put the `'ngRoute'` but when I click to submit the form (remebering that I want to POST data and go to the Bills_Angular View), happens the following with the URL `http://localhost:50840/Home/newBillsToPay#/Bills_Angular` i.e. `http://localhost:50840/Home/where-I-am#/where-I-want-to-Go` and I expect just `http://localhost:50840/Home/Bills_Angular` has something that I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: I've thought that you want to change view in angular but in this case you can use 'location.replace("http://your location")'

Comment: Didn't work yet, strange, do you think that this require a `$routeProvider`? I put this `$location.path("/Bills_Angular").replace();`

Comment: In this case window.location = "/your location" has to work and it don't need $routeProvider. You new $routeProvider only if you want change the view "inside " angular app

Comment: `window.location` works, $location didn't. I can work with `window.location` no problem. Thanks!